# JavaScript, can't seem to export modules?

Tags: javascript, module

So I just started learning JavaScript. I am using plain JavaScript, and following the course on Code academy. Coming from C# I understood modules something like namespaces in C#. I am having trouble exporting, as well as importing them:

```
 let Module = {
 name: 'Hello'
};
export default Module;
```

This throws me an error - 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export'

I also tried the ES5 synthax:

```
 let Module = {
 name: 'Hello'
};
module.exports = Module;
```

This throws me another error - 'Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined'. I am using the newest version of Chrome, and I do not why JavaScript does not recognise these commands. It is very frustrating and cannot wrap my head around it. Therefore, I would like to ask someone to please help me with this problem.

Comment: You need to add the attribute `type="module"` on your script tag.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the newest version of Chrome, it does support ES2015+ modules. You need to ensure your `script` tag says it's a module:

```
<script type="module">
import name from './your-module-file.js';
console.log(name); // {name: "Hello"}
</script>
```

Then your first example will work.

---

But note that `Module` is **not** a module. It's an object you're exporting *from* a module.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have more of a confusion why the ES5 example does not work, and why does it not recognize module.exports? am i missing something? I am doing exactly what Codeacademy does on their website. It works for them but not for me.

Comment: @DaniloDimitrievski Because it's not "ES5", it's common.js module style which assumes semi-global `module` and `require` objects. Browsers don't have those if you don't use a specific library.